# sonata page with sub-site not works

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata, multisite

I try to configure sonata page to work with sub site. So i have my first site with path "\" that is work well. But my sub-site with path "\en" don't want to work. I always have error that there is no page for this path.
I follow the documentation there : [Sonata page documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/page/3-x/doc/reference/multisite.html)

But that don't work, any idea? thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you mean slashes, not backslashes, right?

Comment: You should start by having a look at the output of the `debug:router` command IMO

Comment: I've try debug:router  bug no route /en?

Comment: But i well had my sub-site with this path, I do the same than on demo project of sonata.

Comment: You should try debugging [this file](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataPageBundle/blob/f48a2b7c17740697e30bf5f15e20a300e9870f75/DependencyInjection/SonataPageExtension.php#L346)

Comment: Where should i need to create my \en route if not in the site admin interface?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126519/discussion-between-greg0ire-and-loic).

Comment: I just dump the $multisite variable and it's well 'host_with_path'

Comment: I found my mistake was i had put mydomain in site host and not 'localhost'. Thanks to greg0ire :)